# Media-query loading stylesheet when it shouldn't

Tags: css, media-queries

I've set up a base stylesheet as well as a media-query stylesheet, following a progressive enhancement philosophy, like below:

```
<!-- Empty CSS file; base style for really old mobile browsers (128px,240px,<320px) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" media="all">
<!-- Layout for newer narrow viewport browsers, as well as desktop browsers -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" media="all and (min-width: 20em)">
```

However, when I fire up Firefox and resize it to be less than 320px, it still loads `layout.css` instead of showing me an unstyled page. Why is this?

Additional to that (instead of asking a separate question), if I do add some base styles to `global.css` and add a single media query to `layout.css` then the latter layout is rendered and remains on the page even when I re-size the browser to be less than the minimum width for `layout.css` to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your minimum viewport width for Firefox just happens to be wider than `320px`, meaning that no matter how narrow you resize the window to be, it will never be less than `320px`. Your `layout.css` styles will always be applied in Firefox because the viewport always meets the `min-width` requirement of `320px` (and probably `20em`). Try your current setup in Chrome (Chrome typically has a narrower minimum viewport width), and try something like `min-width: 600px` in Firefox, and your styles should be applied as expected (`layout.css` will be applied when the viewport is at least `600px` wide).

## Edit

This is a good demo site for media queries: [Media Query Playground](http://www.jensbits.com/demos/mq/). It will allow you to see what your minimum viewport width is for various browsers as well- just resize until the width value stops changing. If you make changes to your toolbar (by adding/removing items) in Firefox you can change the minimum viewport width.

Comment: Chrome's min-width seems to be 400px actually (version 16).

Comment: @Simpleton: see my edit- the same should apply for changing your minimum for Chrome (my Chrome's viewport can get down to `191px`. The good news is that your media queries will work, but you just have to have a device/browser that can meet the requirements.

Comment: @Simpleton: I'm not sure about Chrome, but for Firefox just right click on the toolbar in an empty space, click "Customize," and drag items on and off.

Comment: JackieChiles Sorry, think there's some misunderstanding. I know how to add/remove things from the toolbar, but how will doing that allow for the viewport to go down to <200px? My FF goes down to 352px according to the Media Query Playground link. Will adding/removing items to the toolbar decrease this minimum?

Comment: @Simpleton: Sorry if I was unclear- yes, if you remove items from the toolbar, Firefox will let you shrink the viewport further, allowing for a lower minimum size.